# Can I prepare a statement in plain Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, prepared-statement

3GLs provide mechanisms to prepare statements before executing them. E.g.

```
 SELECT name
 FROM people
 WHERE age=:AGE
```

The same query can then be executed for different ages. **But can such a statement also be prepared in a "plain" Oracle SQL client?** Can the same be done in e.g. SQL Plus or dbForge Studio for Oracle as in Java or C# or any other programming language that supports prepared statements?

Comment: Yes, of course, there are ways in Java, C# and may other languages that help us use bind variables or placeholders in a particular query. Java and C#, especially, offer a great degree of control over this.

Comment: I am aware that it can be done in Java and C#, that was not my question. The question is whether it is possible in plain SQL, or at least in SQL Plus or dbForge Studio or Toad or some other program like that.

Comment: Yes. You could do this. But what is the scenario you have? 

See this link for more on bind variables with examples. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76975/oci05bnd.htm

Comment: I have a complex query that I want to develop in dbForge Studio. I want to try it out with different input values. I want the query to be correct before using it in a 3GL program.

Comment: I don't know about dbForgeStudio, but in SqlPlus you can do this by simply replacing colon : with ampersand &. `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = &ID`

Comment: And then how can `&ID` be filled in with an actual value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dbForge Studio for Oracle, named parameters can be used, preceded by a colon `:`

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE name=:name
```

The parameters can then be filled in with the "Edit parameters dialog box", available from the SQL toolbar.

Answer (score -2):

I know you didn't ask about PostgreSQL but about Oracle. However, of note, PostgreSQL has this feature right in its SQL language.

The SQL standard includes a PREPARE statement, but it is only for use in embedded SQL. The PostgreSQL version of the PREPARE statement works like this:

```
PREPARE nameByAge(number) AS
  SELECT name
    FROM People
   WHERE age=$1;
```

and you use it like this:

```
EXECUTE nameByAge(18);

EXECUTE nameByAge(50);
```

So unfortunately for Oracle SQLPlus the answer seems to be no, not bind variables. But SQLPlus has substitution variables, similar to shell scripts. You use them as &1, &2, &3, ... and they get their parameters from the way you call the SQLPlus script.

```
sqlplus user/password @script.sql 18

sqlplus user/password @script.sql 50
```

with the script.sql being

```
SELECT name 
  FROM People
 WHERE age=&1;
```

this would work, even though it is not bind. But then, do you really care about the slight savings in repeat parse time? In fact Oracle hashes SQL statements and already replaces constants with bind variables to be able to better reuse query plans. So the savings you would get with PREPARE and BIND are really minuscule.

Comment: Your post doesn't answer the question. First, it is not about Oracle, second, the scenario is different from the one in the question. If it is helpful for anyone, they will not search for it here. Please find a better place to write down this information, which can be helpful for someone struggling with Postgres.